# Angular - CORS: Read response on failed request

Tags: angular, spring-boot, server

I am using Angular 8 for the front end at my job.

We have an identity management server/service layer that intercepts requests and adds headers based on cookie data it sets on the UI/front end (that is how i currently understand it).

I am trying to send a request to our backend service (testing with a dummy user account) but get a CORS error (somewhat expected) because the response does not have the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header (i'm assuming this is the identity management layer's doing).

Now, the weird thing:

[image]

I can see the status of the response is `403`; this is expected.

However, because the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is not set, i see this:

[image]

[image]

My question is, is there a way to see/get that status in the code despite the request failing?

Comment: No, you need to set the right headers on the server.

Comment: Doc indicating that status code will be 0: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access Control Allow Origin is set by backend, not by frontend. Backend have to trust your domain. You will not be able to get this code because its a option call failing at browser's end. Try to have a error callback in subscribe, if you have some luck.